# Как настроить размер шрифта в Linux Mint?

Tags: шрифты, linux-mint, linux

Здравствуйте. Я поставил себе систему Linux Mint с графическим окружением Cinnamon. Шрифт в системе оказался слишком крупный. Как поменять его размер? В настройках не нашел средств для этого (в графической систем MATE можно было в настройках отображения это менять). Так есть такие программы? Если нет, как можно это сделать через терминал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Щелчок правой кнопкой по панели -> Настройки панели. Дальше, надеюсь, разберетесь.